# How to get a list of all users which pass a specific policy?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization

When a project is added, I fetch all users who have the permission to view it to inform them.
This happens in a listener:

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

// ...

$notifiables = User::all()->filter(function(User $user) use($event) {
    return Gate::forUser($user)->allows('view', $event->project);
});
```

This works. But when I've got 1000 users in my system and 5 are able to view the project, I'm iterating over 995 users for nothing.
And as the event and the listener run synchronously, the user adding a project has to wait for this to happen.

How can I accelerate this?

Edit: Okay, it's possible to queue listeners. However, it would be great to improve this code.

Comment: Please can you show the code for your policy?

Comment: I see where you're heading with this question. I could take a look into the logic of this policy and use it to accelerate this process. But when the policy changes, one might forget to update this. Bugs incoming.

Comment: Well depending on the logic in your policy I was going to suggest a couple of things but if already know that's not going to help then never mind :)

Comment: The project thing is actually just an example. I have multiple listeners that need to find the users to be notified. I have groups with permissions and most of the time the policy checks if the user has a permission. But as I said, things get dangerous when an additional condition is added..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Gate Facade but if it's in a model with relations, you can use whereHas :

```
$users = App\User::whereHas('permissions', function ($q) use ($event) {
    $q->where('name', 'view')->where('model_id', $event->project->id);
})->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's Notifications trait to allow a subscribed user to receive notification events. These notifications can be queued for handling later, sent via email/sms/slack, saved to the DB, or used to broadcast messages like in your use case.

Make new notification

`php artisan make:notification InvoicePaid`

Use *notifiable* trait

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Now the user has a *notify* method that takes a *notification* as an argument

```
use App\Notifications\InvoicePaid;

$user->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/notifications

Tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/notifications-in-laravel--cms-30499

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. The problem is to find out which users should be notified.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood the issue. So it's a DB design issue, not a laravel issue?
Have you tried creating a table for your notifications that have a user_id as their foreign key?
$notifable_users = Notification::select('user_id')->get();